# Dinatural transformation,constant functor,hom functor

Tags: category-theory

Let $U,V$ be functors between categories $C$ and $X$ and let $Y\in Set$.
Why a dinatural transformation $Y\xrightarrow{\cdot \cdot}\hom_X(U-,V-)$ is a function which assigns to $y\in Y$ a natural transformation $U\xrightarrow{\cdot} V$ , moreover with components $Uc\rightarrow Vc$ coming from dinatural transformations 
$U\xrightarrow{\cdot \cdot}V$?

Answer (score 1):

There's no dinatural transformation between $F$ and $G$... however, is this an exercise coming from Mac Lane, chapter about ends and coends?

I think it's rather easy to solve it, but if you want a hint go on reading!

What should a wedge $\tau\colon Y\overset{\bullet\bullet}\to \hom(F-, G-)$ be? Isn't that condition precisely a naturality condition for $\tau(y)_c$? Now that you know this, notice that this means you have a bijective function $\{\tau_{-,y}\mid y\in Y\}\overset{\sim}\to {\rm Nat}(F,G)$, which allows us to identify the two sets. Now the diagram

[image]

where ${\rm Nat}(F,G)\to\hom(Fc,Gc)$ sends a natural transformation to its $c$-component, commutes for a single $h\colon Y\to {\rm Nat}(F,G)$, and this is precisely the desired Universal Property for $\displaystyle \int_c\hom(Fc,Gc)$.

Comment: What I cannot see from the beginning is what a wedge $\tau\colon Y\overset{\bullet\bullet}\to \hom(F-, G-)$ should be. Why is that condition precisely a naturality condition for $\tau(y)_c$?I don't know how the hexagonal diagram collapses to get the naturality condition. You can even forget about $Y$ and explain to me why $\{*\}\overset{\bullet\bullet}\to \hom(F-, G-)$ is a natural transformation.The rest is perfectly clear.

Comment: A dinatural transformation makes an hexagon commute. If this dinatural transformation is a (co)wedge, this exagon collapses into a square. More precisely, two edges of the hexagon become identities.

Comment: But there still remains Y in the collapsed diagram?Can you please draw the collapsed diagram here?

Comment: See the first two pages here http://people.sissa.it/~floregi/stuff/simposio_notes.pdf

Comment: But $\omega_c$ and $\omega_{c'}$ should be horizontal and parallel while in your pdf they go from the same vertex $x_F=Y$.

Comment: A dinatural transformation $P\overset{..}\to Q$ is the thing you know. If $P$ is constant, then $P(f,c), P(c', f)$ are always identity maps. End of the story (pun intended).